# NavigationDrawer margin on Android 4.4 with Translucent Status Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

On Android 4.4 when using the translucent status bar option with ActionBarCompat and NavigationDrawer, the NavigationDrawer listview overlaps the ActionBar slightly. It works fine on all the other API levels I've tested.

As far as I can tell, this is because the `marginTop` option starts from the top of the screen instead of the top of the actionbar (bottom of status bar). 
bottom of the status bar. There is an offset

Is there a workaround for this ? I'm using the example layout and setting the `marginTop` to `?attr/actionBarSize` currently.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. A solid background is used for contrast
     with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_app" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the code here - 
https://github.com/afollestad/kitkat-transparency-demo

That lets you set the translucent status and navigation bars, along with the NavigationDrawer.

Override the onViewCreated in the NavigationDrawer as below -

```
@Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) return;
    SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(getActivity());
    SystemBarTintManager.SystemBarConfig config = tintManager.getConfig();
    view.setPadding(0, config.getPixelInsetTop(true), config.getPixelInsetRight(), config.getPixelInsetBottom());
  }
```

This is assuming that you are using SystemBarTint libary

https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to find the status bar height and set the margin manually.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
  DrawerLayout.LayoutParams lp = (DrawerLayout.LayoutParams) mDrawerList.getLayoutParams();
  lp.setMargins(0, lp.topMargin + getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
  mDrawerList.setLayoutParams(lp);
}

public int getStatusBarHeight() {
  int result = 0;
  int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
  if (resourceId > 0) {
    result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why? I didnt need to do this and yet I got both status and navigation bars translucent along with the NavigationDrawer which has the List inside of it set below action bar. Check screenshots here - http://bit.ly/1nFHBD9 and http://bit.ly/1nFHCak

Comment: The only benefit to this implementation is avoidance of the dependency. If you are going to be using that library anyway, then that one makes more sense. I initially used that approach but didn't want the library in there cause I wasn't really using it.